# wrapfig: titlesec stops figure from appearing

Tags: titlesec, wrapfigure, wrapfig

Simply importing `titlesec` into my document stops a figure in the `wrapfigure` environment from appearing:

[image]

If I comment out `\usepackage{titlesec}`, I get the expected result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3.5in}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Am I using `wrapfigure` incorrectly?

Comment: move it behind the \section command.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you consider adding an answer, and perhaps explaining the principle at stake here?