# Wrapfigure not showing image

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, white-space

I have used `wrapfigure` before with no issues. But this time it just creates the space where the image should be shown. But this one time it only shows me a blank space where the image should be placed.

The moment I place the same function underneath my text it appears. So the redirect is not the problem.

Does anyone have an idea on what it could be?

```
\chapter{Chapter title}
\label{chapter:Chapter title}

\section{Background information chapter}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id.
    
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figures/image}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:image}
\end{wrapfigure}


\section{The use case}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) If I add a document class, the required packages, and use an image I have, everything shows up. Whatever is happening is due to code you are withholding. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Should I edit my post to the new "minimal working example" or do I need to do something else? (I'm new here and trying to learn the proper way of things :) )

Comment: You can simply edit your original post.

Comment: I have found the problem while creating a "minimal working example". The problem was that adding the command: ````\RequirePackage{titlesec}```` made the picture disappear. The simple solution for this is moving the `````wrapfigure````` command behind the ````\section{The use case}````

Comment: Same thing here : [wrapfig: titlesec stops figure from appearing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523193/316068).

Comment: You can put `\section` inside a minipage (`\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-\columnsep`), but either way you will need to decrease the number of lines (wrapfigure optional argument) to match.